# PHP code not working after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to javascript and PHP.  I was implementing recaptcha in my project. here is my code. I use `preventDefault();` to prevent form from submitting and then I checked if the user checked the recaptcha and then submit the form again using `form.submit();` But PHP code is not working.

Javascript :

```
 <script>
        form = document.getElementById("register-form");
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if (!captcha.length > 0) {
                error = document.getElementById("error-msg");
                error.style.display = "block";
                console.log(error);
                error.innerHTML = "Failed!!Captcha Not Completed."
                throw Error("captcha not complete.");

            } else {
                form.submit();
            }
        })
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include('database/connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) {

    #is set to check if the data is empty or not
    echo "test";

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

    $checkEmail = "Select Email from Customer where Email ='$email'";

    $result = mysqli_query(mysql: $connect, query: $checkEmail);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $insert = "Insert into Customer (Firstname,Surname,Age,Gender,Email,Password,Phone,City,Country)
    VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$age','$gender','$email','$password','$phone','$city','$country')";

        $insertresult = mysqli_query(mysql: $connect, query: $insert);
        ($insertresult);
        if ($insertresult) {

            echo "<script>window.alert('Insert Success')</script>";


        } else {
            echo "<script>window.alert('Error')</script>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "window.alert('Duplicate email')";
        echo "</script>";
    }


}




?>
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Also, be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

I got it!! I only need to call `preventDefault()` only if the captcha fails.
Here is my updated JS code.

```
<script>
        form = document.getElementById("register-form");
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      
            const captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if (!captcha.length > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                error = document.getElementById("error-msg");
                error.style.display = "block";
                console.log(error);
                error.innerHTML = "Failed!!Captcha Not Completed."
                throw Error("captcha not complete.");

            } 
        })
    </script>
```